# Dynamic Mail Setting in Queue in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp, jobs

In my Laravel app I have sendmail mails function for all the Queue Jobs and etc.

But now the case comes to me is I have use Dynamic Mail that means there are some mails which are suppose to send through manual SMTP settings.

In my Job I have did this change

```
if (isset($dbMmBank->is_manual_smtp) && $dbMmBank->is_manual_smtp == 1) {

    $oldConfig['mail'] = config('mail');
    // config([
    //     'mail.host' => $dbMmBank->smtp_host,
    //     'mail.port' => $dbMmBank->smtp_port,
    //     'mail.username' => $dbMmBank->smtp_user,
    //     'mail.password' => $dbMmBank->smtp_pass,
    // ]);
    $config = array(
        'driver'     => $dbMmBank->smtp_driver,
        'host'       => $dbMmBank->smtp_host,
        'port'       => $dbMmBank->smtp_port,
        'from'       => array('address' => $dbMmBank->smtp_fromaddress, 'name' => $dbMmBank->smtp_fromname),
        'encryption' => $dbMmBank->smtp_encryption,
        'username'   => $dbMmBank->smtp_user,
        'password'   => $dbMmBank->smtp_pass,
        'sendmail'   => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    );
    // // \Artisan::call('config:clear');
    Config::set('mail', $config);
    print_r(config('mail'));
}
try {
    $emailer = $this->commonService->sendEmail($email, 'SendOfflineApplicationToVendor');
    echo 'Email Sent Successfully!';

    // After Sending the mail we have to reset the config
    if (isset($oldConfig)) {
        print_r($oldConfig['mail']);
        // \Artisan::call('config:clear');
        Config::set('mail', $oldConfig['mail']);
        // sleep(1000);
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error Sending Email: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

But then also it is sending mails through default SMTP. Sometime it starts sending mails through this new mails as well after clearing cache but after that it all the mails are send through that mail only instead of default or manually changed mail until I clear cache or starts new queue.

Answer (score 1):

In your Laravel mail config you can just configure multiple mail configs. No need to switch configs.

Like so:

```
'mailers' => [
    // This is the default configuration
    'smtp' => [
        'transport' => 'smtp',
        'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
        'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
        'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
        'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
        'timeout' => null,
        'auth_mode' => null,
    ],

    // This is the second configuration, used to send info messages
    'info' => [
        'transport' => 'smtp',
        'host' => env('INFO_MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
        'port' => env('INFO_MAIL_PORT', 587),
        'encryption' => env('INFO_MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
        'username' => env('INFO_MAIL_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('INFO_MAIL_PASSWORD'),
        'timeout' => null,
        'auth_mode' => null,
        'from' => [
            'address' => env('INFO_MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'info@example.com'),
            'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
        ],
    ],
    // add more configurations if needed
],
```

And then use them like this:

```
Mail::mailer('info')->to($recipient)->send(new InfoMail($info));
```

```
Mail::mailer('smtp')->to($recipient)->send(new OrderMail($order));
```

Comment: I need it dynamic not  from my mail config.

Comment: In that case you might be better off writing your own MailChannel and custom Mailer, that way it's a bit simpler to switch these around.